# How to log 404 or undefined url's path information in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, redirect, 404, paths

I want to log all urls which redirects to 404, for this I extended Mage_Cms_IndexController's noRoute action, here I can log all urls by

```
Mage::log(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl());
```

Now I want to log url if it is a category. but I can't filter it out.
If I use

```
  Mage::app()->getRequest()->getModuleName();
  Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
  Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName();
```

Above code returns cms, index and no route.

```
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
$url = Mage::getSingleton('core/url')->parseUrl($currentUrl);
$path = $url->getPath();
```

Here `$path` returns the uri i.e url-rewrites
and if i use `getPathInfo()` it returns nothing.

Comment: if you extend the cms controller it will give you the cms path. Fot getting the all types of 404 it is better you implement your own Router

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have to use `getOriginalPathInfo()` returns ORIGINAL_PATH_INFO.

This value is calculated instead of reading PATH_INFO
     * directly from $_SERVER due to cross-platform differences.

```
    public function noRouteAction($coreRoute = null)
    {
      $OriginalPathInfo = $this->getRequest()->getOriginalPathInfo();
      // Log the original path.
      Mage::log($OriginalPathInfo );
      // Let go some other code or return to parent
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it actually logs the url_rewrite path, which i can get from current url, what I want is to get module, controllor and action name from that path. like if i get 404 error on `/bedroom-furniture/bedroom-sets.htm' page, I want to get module catalog, controller->category and action->view here